# Semi-random data sorted compression issue

Tags: random, compression

I have [this](http://pastebin.com/Y0GjEpTD) sorted integer sequence of numbers.

The difference between them is random. However, if you compute the difference of each one you can see that it looks a bit with a logarithm function (the differences increases logarithmically) associated somehow with a random number/function.

I know that this is not a huge amount of numbers, but I have thousands of series like this one (generated by the same algorithm).

I'm trying to compress this data as much as I can. I played mainly with delta compression and could only compress the data to 30% of its original size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (generated by the same algorithm)

Then that algorithm itself likely provides the best compression.  What is it?

Barring that, it's easy to get the data down to about 10K bytes.  Encode the differences with variable-length integers.  Such an integer is represented as a sequence of bytes with the high bit equal to one (any number of those including none), followed by one byte with the high bit equal to zero.  Then concatenate the low seven bits of each byte to get the integer.  The least significant bits came first.

This has the advantage of coding all of the values less than 128 in a single byte.  More than 96% of your differences are less than 128.  A general purpose compressor will then efficiently Huffman code those bytes.

Applying that to your differences, and then compressing with `gzip -9`, I get 10626 bytes.  Forcing the gzip algorithm to use Huffman compression only, I get 10018 bytes.  If I cut the file just before the first high bit equal to one occurs, compress the two pieces separately using Huffman only, and then combine those, I get 9701 bytes.

Update:

Here is the code for generating and decoding variable-length integers:

```
/* Write n as a variable-length integer to out. */
void var(unsigned long n, FILE *out)
{
    int ch;

    do {
        ch = (int)(n & 0x7f);
        n >>= 7;
        if (n)
            ch += 0x80;
        putc(ch, out);
    } while (n);
}

#define ULBITS 64   /* set to the number of bits in an unsigned long */

/* Read a variable-length integer from in, putting it in *n.  Return 0 on
   success, -1 on immediate end-of-file, -2 if end-of-file in the middle of an
   integer, or 1 on overflow of the unsigned long type. */
int unvar(unsigned long *n, FILE *in)
{
    int ch, b;
    unsigned long d;

    *n = 0;
    b = 0;
    do {
        ch = getc(in);
        if (ch == EOF)
            return b ? -2 : -1;
        if (b >= ULBITS)
            return 1;
        d = (unsigned long)(ch & 0x7f) << b;
        if ((d >> b) != (ch & 0x7f))
            return 1;
        *n += d;
        b += 7;
    } while (ch & 0x80);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the algorithm that encode the differences with variable-length integers?

Comment: I had no idea until I googled it just now.  Until then I would have called it "the obvious variable-length integer format".  However it is called VLQ for variable-length quantity, and apparently first showed up in MIDI.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_quantity .  However when I implemented it, I did it in little-endian order instead of big-endian order, as the wikipedia article describes.  Little-endian is simpler.

Comment: Thank you! Is your implementation open source? If yes, where can I find it?

Comment: The implementation of variable-length integers is trivial.  I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As currently stored, the file is 101 KB.

If you store the file as a sequence of 32-bit integers (in binary -- and yes, they're all small enough to do this), that brings you down to 57 KB (14,345 integers x 4 bytes). gzipping that gives you a 21 KB file. That's already over the 30% boundary, but we can do better!

If you instead store each successive difference as a 32-bit integer, that gzips down to 15 KB.

If you want to avoid gzip, we can pull out some fancy tricks. Using a simple [Elias gamma coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding) on each difference generates a 14 KB file. This requires an annoying bitstream reader/writer, though, which may be a turnoff.

You might be able to do even better with an appropriately tuned [exp-Golomb code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential-Golomb_coding); I haven't tried that.